# IllegalThreadStateException while using BasicRobot

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, fest

I'm getting the following while trying to use BasicRobot (FEST). I don't know how to fix this.

```
[ConditionalEventPump] Exception occurred during event dispatching:
java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: Cannot call method from the event dispatcher thread
    at org.fest.swing.core.BasicRobot.waitForIdle(BasicRobot.java:669)
    at org.fest.swing.core.BasicRobot.waitForIdle(BasicRobot.java:654)
    at org.fest.swing.core.BasicRobot.click(BasicRobot.java:426)
    at org.fest.swing.core.BasicRobot.click(BasicRobot.java:387)
    at org.fest.swing.core.BasicRobot.click(BasicRobot.java:372)
    at org.fest.swing.core.BasicRobot.click(BasicRobot.java:360)
    at org.fest.swing.driver.ComponentDriver.click(ComponentDriver.java:94)
    at org.fest.swing.fixture.JButtonFixture.click(JButtonFixture.java:99)
```

Here is the code:

```
BasicRobot robot = (BasicRobot) BasicRobot.robotWithCurrentAwtHierarchy()

MainFrame.button( "setup" ).click();
//Exception is thrown in this line
DialogFixture setupViewDialog = WindowFinder.findDialog( "setup" ).using( robot );
setupViewDialog.button( "Save" ).click();
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you can't call `click()` from the EDT, so start a new thread to call it, like so:

```
BasicRobot robot = (BasicRobot) BasicRobot.robotWithCurrentAwtHierarchy()

new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override 
    public void run() {
        MainFrame.button("setup").click();
    } 
}).start();
DialogFixture setupViewDialog = WindowFinder.findDialog( "setup" ).using( robot );
new Thread(new Runnable() { 
    @Override
    public void run() {
        setupViewDialog.button("Save").click();
    } 
}).start();
```

Comment: It actually does click on the setup button that sits on the mainframe, however after that I get the exception. I'm guessing the exception is being thrown while finding the dialogFixture...

Comment: @Mehmet Yesin: But the stacktrace shows that `click` was called.